# Existence of a Random Variable with given Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ be a probability space, $x : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be measurable and 
$\nu : \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{m}) \to [0,1]$ be a kernel such that

1. For every $F \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{m})$ the map $\nu(\cdot,F)$
   is measurable
2. For every $\tilde{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ the map $\nu(\tilde{x},\cdot)$
   is a probability measure

From this, can we claim the existence of a random variable $y$ such 
that $P(y \in F | x = \tilde{x}) = \nu(\tilde{x},F)$ holds for every $\tilde{x}$ and $F$?

Comment: What is $p$?...

Comment: @amsmath, please check now.

Comment: There need not be such a random variable $y$ defined on $\Omega$ itself.  But if you are willing to enlarge the probability space, you can find one.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222702/sufficient-conditions-on-target-space-for-the-existence-of-regular-conditional-p

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, can you point me to a reference.

Comment: I think I got the idea of enlarging the probability space. Thanks.